# Fetching streaming links from odnoklassniki results in 400 Bad request

Tags: java, android

I'm currently working on an app that supports showing streams from many websites, including youtube, facebook, etc. One of the websites is `odnoklassniki` or `ok.ru`. I'm doing the fetching from client-side using an ASync-Task.

Basically, I'm fetching the HTML content and searching for the json response, which is `videos`. This array has the complete list of the videos. Before being able to use it, I need to convert the HTML entities.

After clicking the resulting link, I'm getting an integer shown on the webpage, which is basically a `400 Bad Request`. When trying with a download manager on PC, the download link works, even though they're both the same link. I've checked the sent headers and made sure it's the same.

example link: https://ok.ru/video/1743464696339

I'm able to show the list in the interface connection, but the resulted link is useless. The link doesn't get the streaming link of the video.

The result looks like this `https://vd54.mycdn.me/?expires=1556116458279&srcIp=IPHERE&srcAg=CHROME&type=3&sig=XSVrS1J_88o&ct=4&urls=IPHERE&clientType=0&id=613619010067&bytes=0-2075`

```
private static class OKRUTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private StreamingInterface mStreamingInterface;
    private String mURL;
    private List<ItemStreamOption> mStreamingOptions;

    public OKRUTask(String mURL, StreamingInterface mStreamingInterface){
        this.mURL = mURL;
        this.mStreamingInterface = mStreamingInterface;
        mStreamingOptions = new ArrayList<>();
    }


    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        try{
            Document mDoc = Jsoup.connect(mURL)
                    .ignoreContentType(true)
                    .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
                    .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
                    .header("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3")
                    .header("Accept-Language", "it-IT,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,de;q=0.4,it;q=0.2,es;q=0.2")
                    .header("Origin", "https://ok.ru/")
                    .header("Referer", "https://ok.ru/")
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36")
                    .referrer("https://ok.ru/")
                    .maxBodySize(0)
                    .timeout(600000)
                    .followRedirects(true)
                    .ignoreContentType(true)
                    .get();
            String mHTML = mDoc.toString();
            mHTML = mHTML.replace("&quot;", "\"");
            mHTML = mHTML.replace("\\\"", "\"");
            mHTML = mHTML.replace("\\u0026", "&");

            String mSources = getStringInBetweenRegex(mHTML,"\"videos\":[","]");
            mSources = "[" + mSources + "]";
            mSources = mSources.replaceAll("\\/","/");

            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(mSources);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String stream_link = jsonObject.getString("url");
                String stream_quality = jsonObject.getString("name");

                if(stream_quality.contains("mobile")){
                    stream_quality = "144";
                } else if(stream_quality.contains("lowest")){
                    stream_quality = "244";
                } else if(stream_quality.contains("low")){
                    stream_quality = "360";
                } else if(stream_quality.contains("sd")){
                    stream_quality = "480";
                } else if(stream_quality.contains("hd")){
                    stream_quality = "720";
                } else if(stream_quality.contains("full")){
                    stream_quality = "1080";
                }

                mStreamingOptions.add(new ItemStreamOption(stream_quality,stream_link));

            }

        } catch (Exception e){
            mStreamingInterface.triggerResult(null, true, e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        mStreamingInterface.triggerResult(mStreamingOptions, false, null);
    }
}
```

getStringInBetweenRegex:

```
private static String getStringInBetweenRegex(String mSource, String mFirst, String mSecond){
    try{
        String regexString = Pattern.quote(mFirst) + "(.*?)" + Pattern.quote(mSecond);
        Pattern mPattern = Pattern.compile(regexString);
        Matcher mMatcher = mPattern.matcher(mSource);
        while(mMatcher.find())
        {
            return mMatcher.group(1);
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```